# How to unit test an azure function in Python using event grid trigger

Tags: azure-functions, python-unittest, azure-eventgrid

I have written an azure function using event grid triggers in Python
The thing is that I want to write unit test but I can not find an example of how to do that a mock an event from the event grid.

Any idea about how to create a unit test for an event grid?

Thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test Azure Functions that use Event Grid triggers is to run the Function App locally and then get Azure in the cloud to invoke the function running on the local machine.

Example:
you want to use  [Event Grid to improve the reliability and responsiveness of Blob Storage processing](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Improving-Azure-Functions-Blob-Trigger-Performance-and-Reliability-Part-3-Using-Event-Grid-to-Respond-to-New-Blobs). Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-debug-event-grid-trigger-local) suggests the use of `ngrok`. Now when a blob is added to a container in the cloud, the locally running function on the dev machine will be invoked via `ngrok`.

There is a simpler solution that allows you to invoke the Event Grid triggered function locally.

This approach bypasses Event Grid completely, so it is not a substitute for proper end-to-end testing, it’s more a development-time testing & debugging tool.

Manually Running **Non HTTP-Triggered Azure Functions**

You can manually trigger a `non HTTP-triggered` function (such as a timer triggered or Event Grid triggered function) via a **special HTTP endpoint**.

The endpoint is of the format:
`{host}/admin/functions/{function name}`

> Note: If you want to test after deployment you have to add the logs to know the detailed information.

Refer the [blog](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Testing-EventGridTrigger-Azure-Functions-Locally-(Without-Using-ngrok)) for more information